# How can i see how many times a specific customer has ordered in total?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am giving the full code of the program so you can see its concept. I am new to Python, and I am trying to learn

```
import uuid                #GET A RANDOM ID FOR THE CUSTOMER
from datetime import date  #GET CURRENT DATE
TodayDate= date.today()
place=-1
SpecificCustomerOrders=0
AfterOrder=True
TotalOrders=0
NameCustomerList=[]
AddressCustomerList=[]
CustomerIDList=[]

FirstEmployeeAccountUsername="coffee1"
FirstEmployeeAccountPassword="coffeeshop1"
SecondEmployeeAccountUsername="coffee2"
SecondEmployeeAccountPassword="coffeeshop2"
ThirdEmployeeAccountUsername="coffee3"
ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword="coffeeshop3"

print("Welcome to our coffee shop!")
print("Login")


#EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCCESS STARTS
LoginEnter=True
while LoginEnter:
    username=input("Username: ")
    password=input("Password: ")
    if username==FirstEmployeeAccountUsername and password==FirstEmployeeAccountPassword or username==SecondEmployeeAccountUsername and password==SecondEmployeeAccountPassword or username==ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword and password==ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword:
        print("Login Successful")
        LoginEnter=False
    else:
        print("Invalid Login. Try again")
#EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCCESS ENDS

#PROCCESS AFTER ORDER PLACEMENT STARTS

while AfterOrder:
    place+=1
    CustomerName=input("Customer's Name:")
    CustomerAddress=input("Customer's Address:")
    NameCustomerList.append(CustomerName)
    AddressCustomerList.append(CustomerAddress)
```

> This is where I try to get how many times a specific customer has
> ordered in total but I cant figure it out.

```
    if CustomerName==NameCustomerList[place] and CustomerAddress==AddressCustomerList[place]:
        SpecificCustomerOrders+=1
        if SpecificCustomerOrders==1:
            print("This customer has ordered",SpecificCustomerOrders," time")
        else:
            print("This customer has ordered",SpecificCustomerOrders," times")
        TotalOrders+=1
        CustomerID=uuid.uuid1()
        CustomerIDList.append(CustomerID)
        print("Current Date is:" , TodayDate)
        OrderPrice=input("Total amount of order:")
```

Comment: You should tell us what specific problem you're having

Comment: I want to see how I can save in a variable the number of orders a specific customer(not all customers) has placed.

Comment: It's a bit confusing because we don't know where your second code segment is actually located in your code. Does this belong to some kind of loop? Or is it also part of the `while AferOrder:`? The `if` condition `if CustomerName==NameCustomerList[place] and...` will always be true because you just appended the corresponding value to the list.

Comment: (You are right it is confusing) It's also a part of the `while AfterOrder:`..... Ok I can fix it to not always be true but how does this fix my problem?

Comment: It's still not really clear what you try to achieve. What should be the difference between `SpecificCustomerOrder` and `TotalOrders`, why do you assign a new ID with every order and what output do you get vs. what do you expect?

Comment: What i am trying to do with `SpecifcCustomerOrder` is everytime I see that a `CustomerName` and a `CustomerAddress` is getting inputted again , `SpecificCustomerOrder+=1`....Ignore the `TotalOrders` variable I thought I had deleted it . With the Customer ID the exercise that I am currently doing said that every customer should have his own ID

Comment: This is the output i am getting : https://prnt.sc/vogfbp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a different approach

```
import uuid  # GET A RANDOM ID FOR THE CUSTOMER
from datetime import date  # GET CURRENT DATE

TodayDate = date.today()

Customers = {}

FirstEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee1"
FirstEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop1"
SecondEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee2"
SecondEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop2"
ThirdEmployeeAccountUsername = "coffee3"
ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword = "coffeeshop3"

print("Welcome to our coffee shop!")
print("Login")

# EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCCESS STARTS
LoginEnter = True
while LoginEnter:
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    if username == FirstEmployeeAccountUsername and password == FirstEmployeeAccountPassword or username == SecondEmployeeAccountUsername and password == SecondEmployeeAccountPassword or username == ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword and password == ThirdEmployeeAccountPassword:
        print("Login Successful")
        LoginEnter = False
    else:
        print("Invalid Login. Try again")
# EMPLOYEE LOGIN PROCCESS ENDS

# PROCCESS AFTER ORDER PLACEMENT STARTS

while True:
    CustomerName = input("Customer's Name:")
    CustomerAddress = input("Customer's Address:")

    if CustomerName in Customers:
        Customers[CustomerName]['Orders'] += 1
    else:
        Customers[CustomerName] = {}
        Customers[CustomerName]['Address'] = CustomerAddress
        Customers[CustomerName]['ID'] = uuid.uuid1()
        Customers[CustomerName]['Orders'] = 1

    print("This customer has ordered {} time(s)".format(Customers[CustomerName]['Orders']))

    print("Current Date is: {}".format(TodayDate))
    OrderPrice = input("Total amount of order:")
```

Comment: WOW . thanks a lot man , i will see how you did and I will try to understand it . Thanks again

Comment: It's just a nested dictionary with one entry per customer. The problem with your approach was that you couldn't differentiate between different customers as you had only one order counter.

Comment: `else:
        Customers[CustomerName] = {}
        Customers[CustomerName]['Address'] = CustomerAddress
        Customers[CustomerName]['ID'] = uuid.uuid1()
        Customers[CustomerName]['Orders'] = 1`  can you explain what this does

Comment: It creates a new customer entry in the dictionary. Do you know how dicts are structured, key and value? Maybe it helps if you print the current dict out after every run. Therefore just add a `print(Customers)` at the end

Comment: i havent worked with dictionaries yet only with lists

Comment: Okay, give it a go. To be honest this isn't a perfect solution either because now we're just checking for customer name so you cannot have two customers with the same name. But when you get your head around dicts I'm sure you find a way to solve that problem as well